# sort javascript array in custom way - A..a, B..b, ... , Z..z using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

i am trying to use lodash for sorting array in project. i was checking documentation and i found this ->

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'Fred',   'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'Barney', 'age': 34 }
];
 
_.sortBy(users, 'user');
```

when i run this code the output i get is->

```
0: Object {user: "Barney", age: 34}
1: Object {user: "Fred", age: 40}
2: Object {user: "barney", age: 36}
3: Object {user: "fred", age: 48}
```

But what i want is this ->

```
0: Object {user: "Barney", age: 34}
1: Object {user: "barney", age: 36}
2: Object {user: "Fred", age: 40}
3: Object {user: "fred", age: 48}
```

the sorting order should be something like this ->

```
A..a,  B..b,  .....  Z..z
```

Can someone help me here?
or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use vanilla JS by using [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator#options) and [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). You can specify an option of `caseFirst` as `"upper"` to sort uppercase letters first:

```js
const users = [ { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 }, { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 }, { 'user': 'Fred',   'age': 40 }, { 'user': 'Barney', 'age': 34 } ];

const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {caseFirst: 'upper'});
const res = users.sort((a, b) => collator.compare(a.user, b.user))
console.log(res);
```

The same can be achieved with [`.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/), but using `Intl.Collator` can help with [performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#performance) for larger arrays:

```js
const users = [ { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 }, { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 }, { 'user': 'Fred',   'age': 40 }, { 'user': 'Barney', 'age': 34 } ];

const res = users.sort((a, b) => a.user.localeCompare(b.user, undefined, {caseFirst: "upper"}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: this is working. but first priority is using lodash. so is there a way i can achieve same thing using lodash?

Comment: @mordor619 as far as I'm aware, lodash's sorting methods such as `_.orderBy` and `_.sortBy` don't allow you to pass a custom comparator function. If the concern is browser support, both `Intl.Collator` and `.localeCompare` have [good browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_collator_supportedlocalesof)

Comment: @mordor619 You can expect lodash v5 to support a method that allows for a custom comparator ([details](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/pull/3764))

Comment: what is the `undefined` parameter in 2nd solution?

Comment: It is the locale. Loosely, it specifies the "language" that the strings being compared are. You can see the  [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#examples) from the documentation I linked above to get a better idea.

Comment: so if we give undefined will it consider automatically?

Comment: @mordor619 Yeah, it will use the system default if undefined is supplied

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way :

```
_.sortBy(users, [function(o) { return o.user.toLowerCase(); },'age']);
```

simply in first index change user's name to lowercase and in second set age to sorted by age

Comment: Unfortunately, this still isn't right... the idea isn't to sort by `age`, but to sort by `user` such that the case items come first (only reason I mentioned age before was that that's how you can see your previous answer wasn't sorting the objects correctly by `user`). The main issue is that your `user` property holds lowercased user names, and not the original casing ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCfX9.png)), which doesn't align with OPs expected output

Comment: that's right, that my previous answer, now check it out @NickParsons

Comment: I see,  the output looks better, but I don't think we can assume that we can use `age` to perform the sorting, based on OPs explanation, they want to sort uppercase letters first and then lowercase. If for example there instead of `{ 'user': 'fred', 'age': 48 }` it was `{ 'user': 'fred', 'age': 10 }`, then `fred` would come before `Fred` right, which isn't correct based on OPs ordering

Comment: aha,got it,you are right, I misunderstood the question @NickParsons